# The number of critical points

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know if it's possible estimate the number of critical points that a function is able to have, because, I have the follow problem

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be function of class $C^2$

$$f''(x)+xf'(x)=\cos(x^3f'(x))$$

Does $f$ admit at most a critical point?

I know that's true, but I don't know how to prove it!

Also, is there any way to discover the parity of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hypothesis of this question, $f(x)$ has ***at most one*** critical point.

I argue as follows:

First of all, we observe, from scrutiny of the given equation satisfied by $f(x)$,

$f''(x)+xf'(x)=\cos(x^3f'(x)), \tag 1$

that

$f''(x_c) = 1 \tag 2$

at every critical point $x_c$ of $f(x)$. For

$f'(x_c) = 0 \tag 3$

by the definition of critical point.  Setting $x = x_c$ in (1) yields

$f''(x_c) + x_c f'(x_c) = \cos(x_c^3 f'(x_c)), \tag 4$

or

$f''(x_c) + x_c \cdot 0 = \cos (x_c^3 \cdot 0), \tag 5$

whence

$f''(x_c) = \cos 0 = 1 \tag 6$

as asserted.

Now since $f''(x)$ is continuous, we may for every critical point $x_c$ pick a real $\mu_c$ with $0 < \mu_c < 1$

and find $\delta_c > 0$ such that

$s \in (x_c - \delta_c, x_c + \delta_c) \Longrightarrow f''(s) > \mu_c; \tag 7$

then for $x \in (x_c, x_c + \delta_c)$,

$f'(x) - f'(x_c) = \displaystyle \int_{x_c}^x f''(s) ds \ge \int_{x_c}^x \mu_c ds = \mu_c(x - x_c) > 0; \tag 8$

by virtue of (3), this becomes

$f'(x) > 0; \tag 9$

likewise for $x \in (x_c - \delta_c, x_c)$,

$- f'(x) = f'(x_c) - f'(x) = \displaystyle \int_x^{x_c} f''(s) ds \ge \int_x^{x_c} \mu_c ds = \mu_c(x_c - x) > 0, \tag{10}$

i.e.,

$f'(x) < 0; \tag{11}$

(9) and (11) together show that for any critical point $x_c$

$x \in (x_c - \delta_c, x_c) \Longrightarrow f'(x) < 0,\; x \in (x_c, x_c + \delta_c) \Longrightarrow f'(x) > 0; \tag{12}$

we also see from (12) that the critical points of $f(x)$ are *isolated*, that is, there is a finite distance in $x$ between any two of the $x_c$.

Now suppose $f(x)$ has more than one critical point; then by what we have just shown, there must exist two critical values $x_{c1} < x_{c2}$ with no critical point between them, i.e.,

$x \in (x_{c1}, x_{c2}) \Longrightarrow f'(x) \ne 0; \tag{13}$

furthermore, by (12) there are $\delta_{c1}$ and $\delta_{c2}$ such that

$x_{c1} + \dfrac{\delta_{c1}}{2} < x_{c2} - \dfrac{\delta_{c2}}{2}, \tag{14}$

$f'(x_{c1} + \dfrac{\delta_{c1}}{2}) > 0, \; f'(x_{c2} - \dfrac{\delta_{c2}}{2}) < 0, \tag{15}$

and

$x \in [x_{c1} + \dfrac{\delta_{c1}}{2},x_{c2} - \dfrac{\delta_{c2}}{2}] \Longrightarrow f'(x) \ne 0; \tag{16}$

but now we have $f'(x)$ continuous on $[x_{c1} + \dfrac{\delta_{c1}}{2},x_{c2} - \dfrac{\delta_{c2}}{2}]$ and taking values with opposite signs on the endpoints of this interval; by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there must exist some $x_c \in [x_{c1} + \dfrac{\delta_{c1}}{2},x_{c2} - \dfrac{\delta_{c2}}{2}]$ with $f'(x_c) = 0$, in contradiction to (16); therefore, $f(x)$ has at most one critical point on all of $\Bbb R$.

Must $f(x)$ have ***at least one*** critical point, implying in light of the above it has ***exactly one***?  Perhaps a further analysis of (1) would provide an answer to this question, but I don't have one as of this writing.  Nor do I have, at the moment, any words on the parity of $f(x)$.

Finally, there are some general results available on estimating the number and nature of critical points a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ may have; for example, if they are *non-degenerate*, meaning $f''(x_c) \ne 0$, one can see they must alternate between local maxima and minima; further results may be available if more hypotheses are placed upon $f(x)$; remember, google is your friend . . .